# Make an articles list in PHP

Tags: php, list, hyperlink, file-get-contents, page-title

How can I make a page in PHP that loads various bits of information from a specific directory (i.e. articles/) then returns that to the page in a list.
I need the page to gather the *$title* of all files in a directory, make the title a **hyperlink** to that file and put them into a **list ordered by the *$date*** (**most recent** at the top and only the **top 10** most recent listed) with the *$description* also included, but only a limited amount of words. Then concluded with a **"Read More"** link that leads to the article itself. On the right side of the page I want a list that lists all of the files, but just the titles linked to those pages, nothing else.

All the files in the directory will look similar to this:

```
<?php
$title = "How to...";
$description = "Description";
$keywords = "yes, no, maybe, so";
$date = "2017-02-10";
$content = "<i>This is my content.</i>";
include 'layout/article_template.php';
?>
```

This is the PHP that I have so far, but it doesn't get the parts I need. If I put *$title* in it, it just takes the *$title* of the **article list page** (the page that is supposed to list the titles of files in another directory).

```
<div id="content">
<?php
$dir_open = opendir('articles/');

while(false !== ($filename = readdir($dir_open))){
    $dirArray[]=$filename;

    if($filename != "." && $filename != ".."){
        $link = "<a href='./$filename'> $filename </a><br />";
        echo $link;
    }
}

closedir($dir_open);

$indexCount=count($dirArray);

sort($dirArray);
?>
</div>
```

I am new to PHP and don't know the syntax very well.

Answer (score 0):

Consider putting your variables in JSON format. This way you can easily parse it with PHP without having to [eval](https://secure.php.net/eval) (dangerous) the code.

An example below:

JSON:

```
{
    "title": "How to...",
    "description": "Description",
    "keywords": "yes, no, maybe, so",
    "date": "2017-02-10",
    "content": "<i>This is my content.</i>"
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$articles = [];
foreach (glob('articles/*') as $article) {
    $content = file_get_contents($article);
    $articles[] = json_decode($content);
}
print_r($articles);
```

I'll leave the sorting to you, but this should get you up and running. Good luck!

Sources:

- [glob](https://secure.php.net/glob)
- [foreach](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php)
- [json_decode](https://secure.php.net/json_decode)